# php query select mysql to column for table grid

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I have mysql table like this

```
| idx|  name  | year | month | value |
| 1  |  foo   | 2017 | 1     | bar1  |
| 2  |  foo   | 2017 | 2     | bar2  |
| 3  |  foo   | 2017 | 3     | bar3  |
| 4  |  foo   | 2017 | 4     | bar4  |
```

I want to query for grid table like this

```
| idy |  name  | year | month1  | month2 | month3 | month4 |
| 1   |  foo   | 2017 | bar1    | bar2   | bar3   | bar4   |
```

how can do this, thanks alot

i mean query rows to one row, i want to fill table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>name</th>
       <th>year</th>
       <th>month1</th>
       <th>month2</th>
       <th>month3</th>
       <th>month4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row[id]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[name]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[year]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[month1]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[month2]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[month3]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[month4]; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where is your query ?

Comment: like select * from table where name='foo' and year=2017 .....blablabla i don't know how to do that

Comment: That's all the query you need.

Comment: no sir, i just want to select for table like that

Comment: This transformation is called pivoting and this question has already been asked and answered here on SO several times. The two duplicate topics explain how to create a pivot table within MySQL. However, it may be more effective to do the pivoting within the application (in php in this particular case).

Comment: Yes, sir. It really is.

Answer (score 2):

A couple ways you can accomplish what you need.

The first would be with a group by with a MAX condition.

```
SELECT 
    p.name, 
    p.`year`, 
    MAX(IF(p.`month` = 1, p.value, NULL)) AS month1, 
    MAX(IF(p.`month` = 2, p.value, NULL)) AS month2,
    MAX(IF(p.`month` = 3, p.value, NULL)) AS month3,
    MAX(IF(p.`month` = 4, p.value, NULL)) AS month4
FROM table_name AS p
GROUP BY p.name, p.`year`
```

Another approach would be with joins for each month you want to retrieve.

```
SELECT 
  p.name,
  p.`year`, 
  m1.value AS month1, 
  m2.value AS month2, 
  m3.value AS month3, 
  m4.value AS month4
FROM table_name AS p
LEFT JOIN table_name AS m1
ON m1.name = p.name AND m1.`year` = p.`year` AND m1.`month` = 1
LEFT JOIN table_name AS m2
ON m2.name = p.name AND m2.`year` = p.`year` AND m2.`month` = 2
LEFT JOIN table_name AS m3
ON m3.name = p.name AND m3.`year` = p.`year` AND m3.`month` = 3
LEFT JOIN table_name AS m4
ON m4.name = p.name AND m4.`year` = p.`year` AND m4.`month` = 4
#....
WHERE p.name = 'foo' AND p.`year` = 2017
GROUP BY p.name, p.`year`;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6de54a/3

Results of both would be the same, however your ID would no longer be relevant, as you're grouping the individual rows into a single row, so I will leave it to you on how you want to display the ID.

---

Alternatively you can use PHP to transpose the data, separating the display by using an array key of the name and year.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/KvCD5

```
//SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = 'foo' AND `year` = '2017';

$data = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $key = $row['name'] . '_' . $row['year'];
  if(!isset($data[$key])){
     $data[$key] = array(
         'id' => $row['id'],
         'name' => $row['name'],
         'year' => $row['year']
    );
  }
  $data[$key]['month' . $row['month']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [foo_2017] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => foo
            [year] => 2017
            [month1] => bar1
            [month2] => bar2
            [month3] => bar3
            [month4] => bar4
        )

)
```

---

Then you would iterate over the transposed data.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>name</th>
       <th>year</th>
       <th>month1</th>
       <th>month2</th>
       <th>month3</th>
       <th>month4</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['month1']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['month2']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['month3']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['month4']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: @fyrye thanks a lot you save me

Comment: @Shadow As many times as you have for specific use-cases. I answered the OP's specific use-case, which was both correct and helpful. where the question you marked as duplicate does not provide. `GROUP BY id` vs `GROUP BY name, year` Marking it as duplicate suffices to point others to similar answers, but this question may also apply to other use-cases.

Comment: Yeah, an if a user asks how to join two tables and there is no duplicate that show exactly those fields that the OP joins on, then there is  a specific use case to answer the question again... This way none of the questions could be closed as duplicates.